# Java Array to List Issue

Tags: java

I have following Java code,

```
int a[] = new int[] {20, 30} ;
List lis = Arrays.asList(a) ;
System.out.print(lis.contains(20));
```

However, output is false. Can anybody help me, why this is not giving True ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you get is not a list of integers but a list of integer arrays, i.e. `List<int[]>`. You can't create collections (like `List`) of primitive types.

In your case, the `lis.contains(20)` will create an `Integer` object with the value 20 and compare that to the int array, which clearly isn't equal.

Try changing the type of the array to `Integer` and it should work:

```
Integer a[] = new Integer[] {20, 30} ;
List lis = Arrays.asList(a) ;
System.out.print(lis.contains(20));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any other way to solve this ? Means convert array in such thus can use contains and delete method ?

Comment: You can't solve it any other way without library support (or implementing a wrapper `List` yourself), but if you use Guava, you can use [`Ints.asList(int[])`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) on an `int[]` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The static method asList uses as parameter varargs: `...`. Only by requiring `<Integer>` you prevent a `List<Object>` where a is an Object.

```
int[] a = new int[] {20, 30} ;
List<Integer> lis = Arrays.asList(a) ;
System.out.print(lis.contains(20));
```